# Logic grid puzzle with five FBI officers

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

My friend sent me this puzzle over Discord asking if I could figure it out. I tried for over an hour and I got pretty far but I've hit a bump. The puzzle goes as follows,

There are five colored doors to offices, all in a row at the FBI Headquarters. In each office sits an expert in a different forensic specialty. Each scientist has an instrument on their desk, a favorite crime TV show/hero, and has graduated from a different university.

1. The Criminologist expert has the office with the red door.
2. The Evidence Technician expert has a digital balance on the desk.
3. "Murder She Wrote" quotes are posted in the office with the green door.
4. The Pathologist expert enjoys a good Sherlock Holmes story.
5. The office with the green door is immediately to the right of the office with the purple door.
6. The scientist who graduated from Purdue University has a microscope on the office desk.
7. The Northwestern University graduate has the office with the yellow door.
8. The expert in the middle office watches old reruns of Dragnet with Sergeant Friday.
9. The Document Examiner sits in the first office on the left.
10. The expert who graduated from University of Missouri-Rolla works in the office next to the expert with the magnifying glass.
11. The scientist from Northwestern University sits in the office next to the expert who keeps a tape measure on the desk.
12. The scientist who graduated from Rice University watches Law and Order.
13. The Anthropologist expert graduated from DePauw University.
14. The Document Examiner has an office next to the expert in the office with the blue door.

Questions:

1. Who watches Quincy?
2. Which expert owns the tweezers?

Comment: Is there a specific name for this type of puzzle? I remember they used to publish puzzle books of them, with a grid layout for marking right/wring answers

Comment: @Mohirl they are sometimes called "Einstein's puzzles"; here on PSE we call them "logic grids". For more info, you can check the [tag wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/logic-grid/info).

Comment: I think Einstein's fish puzzle (https://udel.edu/~os/riddle.html) is the most famous logic puzzle of this kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire table is (the `Pos` column is the position of the office starting from the left):

> **`Pos | Colour |   Specialty   | Instrument |  Show/Hero  |  University`**  
>   `1  | Yellow |  Doc Examiner | Mag. Glass |   Quincy    | Northwestern`
>   `2  |  Blue  |  Pathologist  |    Tape    |  Sherlock   |   Missouri`   
>   `3  |  Red   | Criminologist | Microscope |   Dragnet   |    Purdue`  
>   `4  | Purple | Evidence Tech |  Balance   | Law n Order |     Rice`  
>   `5  | Green  | Anthropologst |  Tweezers  |   Murder    |    DePauw`

So the person who watches Quincy is

> the Document Examiner

And the person who has the Tweezers at their desk is

> the Anthropologist